# update using join in select not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
update tableA 
set tableA.col3 = col2 
from (select tableA.col1, tableB.col2 from 
tableA inner join tableB on tableA.col1=tableB.col4 and 
tableA.col3!=tableB.col2 limit 10)  
where tableA.col1 = col1;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from (select ...

What is wrong with above update though below select statement works fine

```
select tableA.col1, tableB.col2 
from tableA 
inner join tableB on tableA.col1=tableB.col4 
    and tableA.col3!=tableB.col2 limit 10
```

Comment: How many rows you want to update plus why you are using select query with update query?

Comment: @NishantGupta I need to update around 50 million rows and want to use limit to process batchwise thats why using select query, any other solution?

Comment: Provide the table structures then i think we can try to provide you help

Answer (score 0):

you have some missing aliases here

```
update tableA set tableA.col3=col2
```

It should be

```
update tableA set tableA.col3= tableB.col2
```

and here

```
where tableA.col1=col1;
```

should be

```
where tableA.col1 = tableB.col1;
```

Comment: what about using "where tableA.col1 = col4;", in the last part?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UPDATE tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB 
ON tableA.col1=tableB.col4 
AND 
tableA.col3!=tableB.col2
SET tableA.col3 = tableB.col2;
```

**OR**
Using your `SELECT` Query Since I am not clear how you want to update the tableA.

```
 UPDATE tableA 
 INNER JOIN (
             select tableA.col1, tableB.col2 
             from tableA 
             inner join tableB 
             on tableA.col1=tableB.col4 
             and tableA.col3!=tableB.col2 limit 10
            ) AS t
ON tableA.col1 = t.col1
SET tableA.col3 = t.col2
```

**GENERAL SYNTAX** of `UPDATE` with`JOIN`:

```
UPDATE T1, T2,
[INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T1 ON T1.C1 = T2. C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2, 
    T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

Comment: Welcome @DevDev If you find it useful please accept it as the answer.